# Bug Bounty for a reversed Hash

Tags: sha-256

this is just a general question, Is there is a bug bounty from the NSA or anyone else for reversing a SHA HASH, specifically SHA-256?

Comment: Why? Are you able to find a pre-image of a given hash value of SHA-256? Well, SHA-256 is managed by NIST, not NSA and they clearly wait for comments from many experts. Of course, SHA-256 is not coming from competition like SHA3, It is designed by NSA people has a long tradition of MD-based hash functions. Many tried to find pre-image ( not reverse! it is a one-way function that has no reverse in the mathematical sense ) of SHA-256 yet failed!

Comment: If you can reverse a SHA-256 hash in such sense that the hash is broken cryptographically I'll happily offer you 2k in Euro and the promise that I'll help you get a good job. However, you will have to publish your findings in a publicly accessible paper for peer review.

Comment: Bitcoin forms a bug bounty for double SHA256 preimages. It's potentially billions of dollars.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus Can you give a link?

Comment: Bitcoin security depends on double SHA256. Breaking that would at the least give a massive advantage to you for mining, at best let you forge arbitrary transactions.